# Foreach-loop loops too many times and requests other Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I'm trying to display a list of clubs in my index file. I can see in the debugger that this works like normal. It retrieves the data from the database, sends it through the Dal and Bll and ends like expected (With the right model and matching values) in MVC. The problem is that somehow the program expects there to be a diffrent model after looping through all the clubs. So say I have 5 clubs, it will put them all 5 in the table (the debugger shows this) and after the last one it wants to loop again, but with an another model: The UserModel. I can't find the reason why the program expects the UserModel suddenly.

ClubModel has no foreign keys or anything related to UserModel. UserModel has a foreign key called ClubID. This is the only relation I can think of, but since UserModel is not used in the View, Controller and Model I see no reason why the program suddenly expects a UserModel.

Error:
[image: Error message]

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AthleteTracker.Models.ClubModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClubID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Place)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Postalcode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedAt)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UpdatedAt)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (AthleteTracker.Models.ClubModel item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Place)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Postalcode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedAt)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdatedAt)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Controller:

```
using AthleteTracker.Models;
using Enums;
using Logic.Factories;
using Logic.Interfaces.Club;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AthleteTracker.Controllers
{
    public class ClubController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Club
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            foreach (ClubModel item in ClubModelsList())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }

            return View(ClubModelsList());
        }
private List<ClubModel> ClubModelsList()
        {
            IClubLogic logic = ClubFactory.CreateClubLogic();

            List<ClubModel> clubs = new List<ClubModel>();

            var clubDtos = logic.ReadAll();

            foreach (ClubLogicDto club in clubDtos)
            {
                ClubModel clubModel = new ClubModel(club);
                clubs.Add(clubModel);
            }

            return clubs;
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
using Enums;
using Logic.Factories;
using Logic.Interfaces;
using Logic.Interfaces.Club;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AthleteTracker.Models
{
    public class ClubModel : IClub
    {
        private IClubLogic logic;
        public int ClubID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Clubnaam")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vul de naam van de club in.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Beschrijving")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vul de beschrijving van de club in.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Plaats")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vul de plaatsnaam in.")]
        public string Place { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Postcode")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vul de postcode in.")]
        public string Postalcode { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Adres")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vul het adres in.")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Land")]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Vul het land in")]
        [DataType(DataType.Custom)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vul het land in")]
        public Countries Country { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        public ClubModel()
        {
            logic = ClubFactory.CreateClubLogic();
        }

        public ClubModel(ClubLogicDto logicDto)
        {
            logic = ClubFactory.CreateClubLogic();
            ClubID = logicDto.ClubID;
            Name = logicDto.Name;
            Description = logicDto.Description;
            Place = logicDto.Place;
            Postalcode = logicDto.Postalcode;
            Address = logicDto.Address;
            Country = logicDto.Country;
            CreatedAt = logicDto.CreatedAt;
            UpdatedAt = logicDto.UpdatedAt;
        }

        public ClubLogicDto ConvertToLogic()
        {
            return new ClubLogicDto(ClubID, Name, Description, Place, Postalcode, Address, Country, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the relevant view. You've created a `List<ClubModel>` as per your code. But `View(ClubModelsList())` is implicitly mapped to a different view (or layout??), which must have a `@model UserModel`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I'm passing in a list of objects into the view 'Index'. When I hover my mouse over view(ClubModelsList()) I see it is view(object model). Plus with the debugger I can see the right view gets loaded. So no, I'm not using a different view.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thank you for the edit! It was indeed in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, there must be a view being rendered which has a `@model UserModel`, while the data passed in is of type `List<ClubModel>`.

You are selecting the view via `return View(...)` without an explicit view name. So either the view selected by convention, or its layout, must have the mis-matched model.